# join tables and perform 'if' and mathematics

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, t_in and t_out

**t_in**

```
id | product | qtd | expire on
```

**t_out**

```
id | t_in | product* | qtd | expire on
```

*(I need a copy in this table to other procedure)

**t_out.t_in** is a foreignkey and I use to avoid excluding a input if a out has been made

**My question is...**

How should be a query to get this table(in one query)?

```
Expire on | qtd

where qtd is (t_in.qtd - t_out.qtd)  ON t_out.t_in=t_in.id
```

I know that can be achieved by left join, but when t_in have no t_out to join, it stays NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is this

`(t_in.qtd - ifnull(t_out.qtd,0))`

But it's not super-clear.